# Call Excel From Acrobat Reader VSTO

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-2007, acrobat

Here is my problem.

I'm making an Excel Template with the Help of VSTO. All the Data display in Excel are comming from a DataBase. In the Excel template I put a Button which open an existing pdf form template, fill it with the data from the DB and save a copy. To do this I used the library ITextSharp which help me a lot. Until here no problem.

Now what I want to do is that each field from the PDF has a link with the cell in Excel. The PDF is read only and it's only a way to display the data stored in the DB. When the user want to modify the value of a field he has to go into Excel to do so. So the goal is that when he want to modify a value in the pdf, he just click on field and he's going to redirect on the correct cell in Excel in order to modify the value.

I don't think there is a way to do this action in JavaScript in Acrobat, because if I'm not mistaken Acrobat won't let you call a macro from the JS.

I was thinking maybe there is a way in VSTO to control Acrobat, but I didn't find it.

If you have any idea on how to do this, I will be greatfull.
Here is part of my code, maybe it will be clearer.

```
        string pdfTemplatePath = @"C:\Files.pdf";
        string pdfFinalFile = @"C:\fileCopy.pdf";
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplatePath);
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(pdfFinalFile, FileMode.Create));

        AcroFields form = stamper.AcroFields;
        foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
        {
            form.SetField(row["Name"].ToString(), row["Value"].ToString());

        }
        stamper.FormFlattening= false;
        stamper.Close();
```